# Unwanted WoWLan wake

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, wake-on-lan

I have a Z390 Aorus Pro Wifi Motherboard whose WiFi adapter has WoWLan support.

I am running Windows 10 1909 Build and I am having a lot of problems getting the WoWLan to work correctly. For some reason, even after activating to wake only from magic packets, the PC wakes up on its own from the NIC (confirmed by the Windows event log) without having any kind of traffic since even the router doesn't see the device anymore.

I have traced all WoL requests over Wireshark and still no rogue WoL requests have been found.
The NIC model is an Intel Wireless-AC 9560. I tried both the latest Intel drivers and the drivers shipped with Windows.

Nothing I do seems to change the behaviour. Only when I uncheck the "allow this device to wake the computer" the wake ups end, but I obviously want to wake my pc over Wireless and cannot keep the option unchecked.

I have disabled fast boot and hibernation, removed every other waking device and wake timer (also UpdateOrchestrator Reboot)

I also forced the NIC to ignore pattern matches.

I have a FritzBox 7490 as a router if that helps.

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No sadly. I am now using a rpi with etherwake which I'm calling from a third party service. The rpi is connected over wifi. Kinda stupid, I know. But it works for now